# list index out of range if i try to print second element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Good afternoon, I'm studying python and trying to divide elements in list that are going after commo and print it. It's working only with the first element and then something happens and it shows me that I'm out of range. Please, if it'not difficult for you, explain why it happens.

txt file:

```
2000.01.04,00:01,104.220,104.220,104.220,104.220,1
```

python file:

```
fl = open('stocks.txt', 'r')

mas = []

for l in fl:
    mas += [l]

for i in mas:
    i = i.split(',')
    print(i[1])
```

So if i try to print i[0], it prints me 2000.01.04, but if i try to print i[1] it doesn' work, although it should print me 00:01

Comment: `mas` contains the entire line `"2000.01.04,00:01,104.220,104.220,104.220,104.220,1"`, so there should be no problem printing `i[1]` when you split it on commas. https://i.stack.imgur.com/reXyM.png

Comment: Do you have the empty line in the end of the file?

Comment: @Parnav Hosangadi Yeah, in theory there should be no problems, but on practise: https://sun9-75.userapi.com/impg/T-EjX36kWo5BcO3mv9OdXDpd7VldXytP5r1jRg/w2tzS1QgRKE.jpg?size=1310x895&quality=96&sign=c7f2295150414873416df8e8363dcf9f&type=album

Comment: @bereal oh, yeah, that's was the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: `I'm studying python and trying to divide elements in list that are going after commo and print it` you could use a list comprehension `print(i) for i in list(filter(None, f1.strip().split(",")))]`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have an empty line, e.g. in the end of the file. Consider checking for that:

```
with open('stocks.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            fields = line.split(',')
            print(fields[1])
```